# Preparing a 19th Century Printed Engraving for Halftone Printing Today. I "Descreened" in Photoshop. Thoughts?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Here's an XCU detail of the original:
[image: Gregor MacGregor from 1823 book]

And here's my finished version:
[image: MacGregor image "descreened" in Photoshop]

Using guidance at link below:

[Descreening in Photoshop](https://bkkphotographer.wordpress.com/2009/08/31/descreening-in-photoshop/)

Comment: You may neutralize comments of blurring a fine engraving if you present the actual problem in details including numbers. For example you are printing something so big and detailed that you suspect or know the details start to interfere with print raster and produce Moire patterns and search help for it.

Answer (score 11):

My thoughts . . .

I wouldn't try to create a halftone to reproduce it. It's a beatiful engraving, so I think better to treat it as though it were line art, so that when printed it isn't converted to a screened image at all.

I found this helpful blog post which describes the basic technique: [Line Art – the One and Only True Bitmap format](https://thelawlers.com/Blognosticator/?p=2269). As it stands, it doesn't really work well with your example image because it's not really high enough resolution, but I think you could tweak it a bit to get a decent enough result.

1. Convert to greyscale
2. Rescale the image by doubling its pixel dimensions. If the scan was 300ppi, this will effectively bring it up to 600ppi which should help keep pixelization to a minimum, or larger if you'd prefer. Alternatively if possible, rescanning it at a higher resolution would be the best.
3. Convert to a Smart Object
4. Apply Unsharp Mask to help retain the detail
5. Apply a levels adjustment layer

[image]

6. Apply a threshold adjustment layer

Tweak 4, 5 and 6 if necessary to try to keep maximum detail in shadows and highlights.

Before final output, convert to bitmap mode, and export as BMP. For peace of mind, request a proof before going to print.

Here's the example, showing the unsharp mask settings. Note that I put the adjustment layers in a group so I could easily toggle them on/off to check with the original.

[image]

100% detail

[image]

Comment: Oh man, I was working on this exact answer! ‍♂️ A few additional tips: Sometimes fiddling with *Shadows* and *Highlights* in *Camera Raw Filter* or simply using *Shadows/Highlights* adjustment can be helpful to make sure you don't loose too much details in neither shadows or highlights. Using *Texture* and *Clarity* in *Camera Raw Filter* can make the details more crisp. *Dust & Scratches* with a *Radius* of 1-2 px can remove some stray pixels after applying *Threshold*.

Comment: Btw: *Doubling* pixel dimensions won't make a 300 ppi image 1200 ppi. You need to *quadruple*! Or simply change *Resolution* from 300 ppi to 1200 ppi with *Resample* ticked on.

Comment: You could, possibly, get better results by upsampling and running smart sharpen instead

Comment: @wolff your right, it would only be 600ppi, but that might be enough. I've edited the answer.

Comment: And of course, rescanning _as bitmap_ might give the best result of all, depending on the original.

Answer (score 5):

You maybe can smooth the engraving so that the presented halftones become smooth gradients. Unfortunately that filtering removes all sharp borders, too and gives to you a blurred image and that's what you already have got.

Nobody will thank you for blurring a finely crafted piece of art, so forget it. Crime investigators, intelligence officers and PhD level mathematicians may have tools which are intelligent enough to guess how an usual photo of the same person possibly would look, but finding it automatically with Photoshop or other ordinary dumb image editing programs is impossible.

One possibility is that you draw selections along the borders which you want to stay sharp. Then you separate the sharp areas to different layers and surface blur the interiors to get smooth gradients. Much work, but not impossible. I guess in practice the result would be bizarre (at best) so I do not recommend it. Preferably do as others have already said: Try to show the engraving as well as possible.

Just to add one way to show what the blurry brownish photo still contains of the original piece of art:

[image]

In the bottom layer there's your photo, but desaturated and lifted to 400% pixel dimensions with Smilla Enlargener. That free program does a remarkable job in guessing which borders should stay sharp and which lines should stay narrow when the image is scaled to bigger pixel dimensions. On1 Resize is a commercial alternative.

The next one above the bottom layer is a sharpening layer. It's a duplicate of the bottom layer and it got Filter > Other > High Pass > 4px. Its blending mode = Hard Light.

Adjustment layer Curves adds contrast. The curve is shown.

On the top there's a Hue&Saturation layer in colorize mode to bring back the brown color. The original color had to be removed by deaturating because increasing contrast generally distorts colors.

BTW if you watch my result in big zoom in you see many areas colored to light brown. That tone were present already in your image as blur. It can occur also in the print where your photo is taken from. It's useless to try to fade it with steep tresholding, because it would remove information. The best presentation of the original needs that blur or alternatively someone should insert numerous fine grooves which obviously have become the blur in printing or when your photo was made.